# How to rank dependent variables

Tags: spss, dependent-variable

1. Statistics and I are mortal enemies.
2. I have an independent variable (gender) and four dependent variables (A,B,C,D). For each of the dependent variable, there were multiple questions with likert scale (1-5) responses.
   I took means, and now I have means for A, B, C and D for all the respondents. 
   I want to show that, for example,
   for Female A occured more than B, than C, than D. 
   for Males, B occured more than C, than A, than D. 
   Can I do this? If so, how?

Thank you. You are basically saving me from a fail grade. And possibly loss of a job offer.